# Tkinter window does not close on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, spyder

I have few lines of code working fine with tkinter on Windows but that do not work on the Mac of my colleague. On Mac when I hit 'OK' the checkboxes window does not close. It looks like this issue has already been raised but that no solution has been found so far. I am curious if this issue has been solved since.

Here are my lines of codes:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('figures')
window.geometry('300x300')
 
l = tk.Label(window, bg='white', width=20, text='figures to plot')
l.pack()
 
        
def check1Clicked():
    if var1.get() :
        puck_path=1
    else:
        puck_path=0
    return puck_path

 
def check2Clicked():
    if var2.get() :
        all_param=1
    else:
        all_param=0
    return all_param
 
def check3Clicked():
    if var3.get() :
        hand_path=1
    else:
        hand_path=0
    return hand_path
        
var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()
var3 = tk.IntVar()

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='puck path',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0) #command=print_selection
c1.pack(anchor=W)
c1.select()# to check the box by default

c2 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='all parameters',variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
c2.pack(anchor=W)
c2.select()

c3 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='hand path',variable=var3, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
c3.pack(anchor=W)
c3.select()


Button(window, text='Ok', command=window.destroy).pack(side=RIGHT)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.quit()` instead of `window.destroy()`?

Comment: Instead of ```window.mainloop()``` ? I tried ```window.destroy()``` but it did not work. I'll try the other one.

Comment: No, here: `Button(window, text='Ok', command=window.destroy)`. What happens if you try `Button(window, text='Ok', command=window.quit)` instead?

Comment: The tkinter window remains opened after hitin ok with ```window.quit```

Comment: Ah darn...sorry - it was worth a shot